# How can I set random-seed of topic model using mallet in gensim?

Tags: python, gensim, topic-modeling, mallet

I had been trying to keep an output of topic modeling stable by using mallet as a library in gensim. However, I found out that mallet can set random-seed but I do not see any parameter in gensim to set it.

Answer (score 2):

This has just been added to the ldamallet.py wrapper

```
    def __init__(self, mallet_path, corpus=None, num_topics=100, alpha=50, id2word=None, workers=4, prefix=None,
             optimize_interval=0, iterations=1000, topic_threshold=0.0, random_seed=0):
    """

    Parameters
    ----------
    mallet_path : str
        Path to the mallet binary, e.g. `/home/username/mallet-2.0.7/bin/mallet`.
    corpus : iterable of iterable of (int, int), optional
        Collection of texts in BoW format.
    num_topics : int, optional
        Number of topics.
    alpha : int, optional
        Alpha parameter of LDA.
    id2word : :class:`~gensim.corpora.dictionary.Dictionary`, optional
        Mapping between tokens ids and words from corpus, if not specified - will be inferred from `corpus`.
    workers : int, optional
        Number of threads that will be used for training.
    prefix : str, optional
        Prefix for produced temporary files.
    optimize_interval : int, optional
        Optimize hyperparameters every `optimize_interval` iterations
        (sometimes leads to Java exception 0 to switch off hyperparameter optimization).
    iterations : int, optional
        Number of training iterations.
    topic_threshold : float, optional
        Threshold of the probability above which we consider a topic.
    random_seed: int, optional
        Random seed to ensure consistent results, if 0 - use system clock.

    """
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue but to use the latest version of `gensim`, it is a little bit tricky. As **Chris** said, the new version has it implemented but running it was troublesome for me. Make sure to do the following as you might be using the old wrapper:

1. `conda install -c conda-forge gensim`
2. `pip install --upgrade gensim`

The second step does the job and just installing it won't update the `gensim` as I had issue with it.

The following links have more info for your question:

[Gensim Installation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/install.html)

[Mallet Wrapper](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/wrappers/ldamallet.html)